# Droid Error. (Newbie Coder)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Ok, so I just started trying to learn how to do some coding yesterday with Eclipse on the android platform. I've coded a lot of other languages, but never in this environment. I don't know why this started happening...

Symptoms: App won't start in Emulator.

```
Debugger Error: "Thread [<8> Thread-8] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))" TutorialThread.run() line: 225
```

This line is a closing bracket.

```
Variables: 
this (TutorialThread (id=30067699104))
c (Surface$CompaitbleCanvas (id-830067697136))
```

---

Like I said though, I am very new to this and I have been following lots of tutorials and lots of Googling. :/ However, I am beating my head on the keyboard on this right now. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

```
package com.Joey_Ant.Lite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;

public class JoeyAnt extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(new Panel(this));
    }
}
class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private TutorialThread _thread;
    private int _x=20;
    private int _y=20;
    private int _x2=20;
    private int _y2=20;
    private int _mx=0;
    private int _my=0;
    private double _angle = 0;
    private int _width=50;
    private int _height=50;
    private double _xchange=0;
    private double _ychange=0;
    private double _speed=5;
    private int _stage=0;
    private int _level=0;
    private int _swidth=0;
    private int _sheight=0;
    private int _bx=0;
    private int _b0w=0;
    private int _b0h=0;
    private int _b0y=0;
    private int _b1w=0;
    private int _b1h=0;
    private int _b1y=0;
    private int _b2w=0;
    private int _b2h=0;
    private int _b2y=0;
    private int _b3w=0;
    private int _b3h=0;
    private int _b3y=0;

    /** 
     * Stage 0 - Main Menu
     * Stage 1 - Controls
     * Stage 2 - Introduction
     * Stage 3 - Game Over
     * Stage 4 - Round Win
     * Stage 5 - In Game
     * 
     */

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _thread.setRunning(true);
        _thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        _thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _thread.join();
                retry=false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //Retry
            }
        }
    }

    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        _thread = new TutorialThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        _mx = (int) event.getX();
        _my = (int) event.getY();
        _x2 = _mx - (_width / 2);
        _y2 = _my - (_height / 2);

        if (_stage==0) {
            if ((_mx > _bx)&&(_mx < _bx+_b0w)) {
                // Within horizontal hit area.
                if ((_my > _b0y)&&(_my < _b0y+_b0h)) {
                    // NEW GAME.
                    _stage=1;
                }

            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        if (_level==0) {
        }
        if (_stage==0) {
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setTextSize(24);
            Bitmap _logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.joeyant);
            Bitmap _newgame = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.new_game);
            Bitmap _resumegame = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.resume_game);
            Bitmap _controls = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.controls);
            Bitmap _credits = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.credits);
            _swidth=canvas.getWidth();
            _sheight=canvas.getHeight();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 225, 199, 77));
            canvas.drawBitmap(_logo, (_swidth/2)-(_logo.getWidth()/2), 20, null);
            _bx=(_swidth/2)-(_newgame.getWidth()/2);
            _b0y=150;
            _b1y=210;
            _b2y=270;
            _b3y=330;
            _b0w=_newgame.getWidth();
            _b1w=_resumegame.getWidth();
            _b2w=_controls.getWidth();
            _b3w=_credits.getWidth();
            _b0h=_newgame.getHeight();
            _b1h=_resumegame.getHeight();
            _b2h=_controls.getHeight();
            _b3h=_credits.getHeight();
            canvas.drawBitmap(_newgame, _bx, _b0y, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(_resumegame, _bx, _b1y, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(_controls, _bx, _b2y, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(_credits, _bx, _b3y, null);
        }
        if (_stage==1) {
            // Introduction!
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(18);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            Bitmap _intro = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.introduction);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 225, 199, 77));
            canvas.drawBitmap(_intro, (_swidth/2)-(_intro.getWidth()/2), (_sheight/2)-(_intro.getHeight()), null);
        }
        if (_stage==2) {
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            Bitmap _scratch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 225, 199, 77));
            canvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, _x, _y, null);
            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(_x)+","+String.valueOf(_y)+" : "+String.valueOf(_x2)+","+String.valueOf(_y2), 20, 20, paint);
            _width=_scratch.getWidth();
            _height=_scratch.getHeight();
            _angle = Math.atan2(_y2-_y, _x2-_x);
            _xchange=Math.cos(_angle) * _speed;
            _ychange=Math.sin(_angle) * _speed;
            if (_x != _x2) {
                _x+=_xchange;
            }
            if (Math.abs(_x2-_x)<_xchange) {
                _x=_x2;
            }
            if (_y != _y2) {
                _y+=_ychange;
            }
            if (Math.abs(_y2-_y)<_ychange) {
                _y=_y2;
            }
        }
    }

}
class TutorialThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private Panel _panel;
    private boolean _run = false;

    public TutorialThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panel panel) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _panel = panel;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                    _panel.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The null pointer line won't be a closing bracket. Make sure your running the latest version of your code when you produce the error, so you get accurate line numbers

Comment: Ok, this makes no sense to me. Now i'm really po'd... I figured I would take a break and come back to it this morning. I did not turn my computer off, just let it go to sleep. I came back and tried it now and it starts up no problem.... What the... There is NO code change whatsoever.... Why would it do that?

Comment: You may of been running an old version of your code. If you try and run your app before it has compiled and built (which takes time, depending on the size of your project) you would be running the old version of your code.

Comment: I wasn't actually going in and clicking on the app. I was letting eclipse automatically start the app when I hit the run / compile button.

Comment: Okay, so I figured out why its doing this, but I don't know how to fix it. Basically when I run something that causes an error in the emulator, it basically locks in the application data that was run at that time. Even if I restart the emulator and eclipse it still uses the old data. So my question then is, how do I force it to use the new code?

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this one out. I reinstalled Eclipse and Android and this stopped happening.